# Automatic visit to different web pages

Tags: internet-explorer

I need to measure the time it takes to load different web pages, each page about once per hour for a week. I suspect that the performance of the networks between my computer and the web-server vary too much over time (not only throughput but also latency).

How can I schedule Internet Explorer to go to certain web pages at certain times? For example the start-page of the local newspaper quarter past every hour. I will log the traffic and post-process some days later (with Wireshark or similar).

Thank you in advance. I have tried to find if this question has already been answered, my apologies if it has.

/Chris

Comment: Does it have to be Internet Explorer?

Comment: Firefox might be ok too. I want to avoid other browsers. /Chris

Comment: How do you know when a page is done loading?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't worked with it myself, but [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) might work for you:

> Selenium is a suite of tools to automate web app testing across many platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This forum post discusses how to run IE with a scheduled task under windows:
http://www.abestweb.com/forums/showthread.php?t=49121

Might be worth a look.

Answer (score 0):

I WEB Tools

http://www.iwebtool.com/speed_test

http://www.linkvendor.com/seo-tools/speedtester.html
http://websiteoptimization.com/services/analyze/

http://www.selfseo.com/website_speed_test.php